# I want to book all flights using ord=all using corelation in load runner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

Using web_reg_save_param i am able to get dynamic value using ord=ALL. And getting value like-
`outbond_flight_1=020;338;07/11/2023 outbond_flight_2=020;332;07/11/2023 outbond_flight_3=020;334;07/11/2023 outbond_flight_4=020;337;07/11/2023.`

but i want to book all flight while running a script.
Please help me because i am new in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `web_reg_save_param` function in `LoadRunner` to capture all the flight values and then use them to book all flights while running a script. Here is an example :

```c
web_reg_save_param("outbond_flight", "LB=outbond_flight_1=", "RB= outbond_flight_2=", "ORD=ALL", LAST);
```

This will capture all the flight values and store them in the outbond_flight parameter which can be used to book all flights while running a script.

Comment: I have tried this but not working.

Comment: @pranaydwivedi , you can try using the web_submit_data function to submit all of the flights at once. do tell me if you need an code snippet of how to use it

Answer (score 0):

> ...I am new to this field.

Your manager needs to send you to training and provide you a mentor for a period of time.   This is an apprenticeship discipline, not a self trained one.